# What is RestSharp doing differently than a simple HttpClient implementation (Endpoint does not accept RestSharp POST)

Tags: c#, xml, rest, restsharp

I was trying to send a POST request with an XML body to an endpoint using RestSharp. I have had good results working with JSON so I wanted to test it once. But I always get a NotAccepted result and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. It must be the way the request is constructed or its content.
I have done the same request with a simple implementation using HttpClient and it works.
So what is RestSharp doing differently to my simple HttpClient implementation?

I want to have a consistent codebase and don't want to rewrite my backend just for this case.

The following are my attempts using RestSharp. But nothing seems to work.

```
var client = new RestClient(new RestClientOptions
{
    Encoding  = new UTF8Encoding(false),
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password, new UTF8Encoding(false)),
    BaseHost = "some.host.url.com"
});

var body = myObject.SerializeToString();

var request = new RestRequest(url);
request.AddHeader("key", value);
request.AddParameter(new BodyParameter(body, "application/xml", DataFormat.Xml));
// request.AddStringBody(body, ContentType.Xml);
// request.AddXmlBody(body, ContentType.Xml);
// request.AddParameter(ContentType.Xml.ToString(), body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
// request.AddParameter("XmlBody", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
// request.AddParameter(new XmlParameter("XmlBody", body, "some.namespace.url", ContentType.Xml));
// request.AddParameter(new BodyParameter("XmlBody", body, ContentType.Xml, DataFormat.Xml));

var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request, cancellationToken);
return response.Content;
```

The following implementation using HttpClient does the job. But I do not see much difference.

```
var body = myObject.SerializeToString();
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "some.host.url.com";

HttpContent content = new StringContent(body, new UTF8Encoding(false), "application/xml");
content.Headers.Add("key", value);

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content, cancellationToken);
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Maybe I am blind by now because I have looked at it many, many times.  Maybe you can tell me how to make the RestSharp code work?

Comment: Did you debug the backend server?  Without seeing the server code you cannot just modify the client.  The server and client have to work together.  Every server is different.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately, the backend server is a black box for me.

Comment: Does the server accept XML? You can't send XML if the server doesn't allow XML.  Do you have the documentation for the back end server?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, the server accepts XML. XML is the only thing it accepts. And yes, there is documentation that tells me about auth and headers and so on. I removed the extra header because it is a simple request.AddHeader(key, value) or request.Header.Add(key,value).
As the implementation works with HttpClient, I think my XML, headers etc are set correctly.
So I'm wondering what RestSharp does differently.

Comment: Startup Fiddler or Wireshark or similar tool and have a look at what is actually sent. From the code I agree that it looks like the same request should be made so without seeing what is actually sent this will be very hard. It might be a default header that is sent using one or the other (some APIs require a user-agent for example).

Comment: There is more than one type authentication see : https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#basic-authentication.  It looks like restsharp want http not https.  Are you getting any response back? if so what is the status code.

Comment: Use requestbin.com to make a sample call from RestSharp and HttpClient, and you'll see the difference clearly.